# is it possible to execute a bash script on remote machine using python pexpect

Tags: python, shell, unix, pexpect

I connected to remote system using Python Pexpect, Now I want to execute some script(available on remote machine) on remote system is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 
you can do it by adding `\n` between the commands

Or,

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh MACHINE')

child.sendline('command1')
child.sendline('command2')
child.sendline('command3')

child.close()
```

I would advice you reading this http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html